# checkbox checkeo y "descheckeo"

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un formulario con tres `select`, que me arrojan ciertos datos de la base de datos y al generarlos, se visualiza una gráfica con el detalle según los `select` seleccionados de año desde 2015 por ejemplo al 2017, y después de seleccionar me aparecen los checkbox seleccionados por defecto. Esto lo realicé con (`checked='checked'`), ya que la gráfica me debe de mostrar todo el detalle la primera vez que el usuario entra a la página.

Mi problema es que cuando yo desactivo los `checkbox` al darle al botón `submit`, sí, me da los datos que requiero, pero no se deselecciona el `checkbox` o no se quita la palomita al refrescar la página.

He buscado por todos lados sin éxito, tal vez mi lógica o lo que estoy haciendo está mal porque no me ha quedado.

Envío la parte del código:

```
<div id="anio_mes" name="anio_mes" >
    <td width="13%" tdwidth="9%"><strong>Anio y mes a deseleccionar:</strong></td>
    <td width="100%">
        <?php

        $query_anio = "SELECT  anio,mes
        FROM [heba].[dbo].[t_rpu_facturacion]
        where anio between '$anioini' and '$aniofin'
        GROUP BY anio,mes
        ORDER BY anio, mes";

        $resulset_anio= consultarMSSQL($query_anio);

        //$b=1;
        while($row_anio= $resulset_anio->fetch()){
            $anomes=trim($row_anio['anio'].$row_anio['mes']);
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $anomes?>"name="<?php echo $anomes?>" value="<?=$anomes?>" checked="checked"  ><?=$anomes?>
            <?php
        }
        mysql_free_result($resulset_anio );
        ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
</div>

<td colspan="3" align="left">

    <a href="javascript:seleccionar_todo()">Marcar todos</a>

    <a href="javascript:deseleccionar_todo()">Marcar ninguno</a> 
    <input type="button" value="Consultar" name="button" id="button" onclick="javascript:deseleccionar(),deselecc()">
```

Las funciones que manejo son estas:

```
function deseleccionar(){ 
//alert(document.getElementById('aniofin').value);
var formulario = document.getElementById("form");
formulario.submit();  
return true;}



 function deseleccionar_todo(){
  for (i=0;i<document.form.elements.length;i++) 
      if(document.form.elements[i].type == "checkbox") 
         document.form.elements[i].checked=0 
         }

function seleccionar_todo(){ 
   for (i=0;i<document.form.elements.length;i++) 
      if(document.form.elements[i].type == "checkbox") 
         document.form.elements[i].checked=1 
}
```

Comment: Tienes algo en el método deseleccionar_todo() ?

Comment: Agrega tu código de JS también por favor

Comment: Crei que no es duplicada, la pregunta que citas trata sobre Habilitar y desabilitar con la propiedad Enabled/Disabled, ésto es Cheched/Unchecked

Answer (score 2):

Tu función deseleccionar_todo() debería tener un comportamiento similar a éste (Jquery):

```
$("input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
```

Por si no está claro, toma todo los input type checkbox y les quita el atributo checked.

Answer (score 0):

¿La pregunta es cómo sabes que está ingresando por primera vez? según lo que yo entiendo siempre que se envíe el formulario actualizaría la página, por lo cual es como si siempre estuviera entrando por "primera vez".

Comment: ésto no parece una respuesta